# How to configure fail2ban file?

Tags: linux, configuration, fail2ban

I installed fail2ban but When I enter fail2ban-client status in the Linux terminal, I get the following warnings:

fail2ban.configreader [1616]: ERROR Found no accessible config files for 'filter.d/murmur' under /etc/fail2ban
fail2ban.configreader [1616]: ERROR  No section: 'Definition'
fail2ban.configreader [1616]: ERROR  No section: 'Definition'
fail2ban.configreader [1616]: ERROR  No section: 'Definition'
fail2ban.configreader [1616]: ERROR  No section: 'Definition'
fail2ban.configreader [1616]: ERROR  No section: 'Definition'
fail2ban              [1616]:ERROR Failed to access socket path: /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock. Is fail2ban running?

By the way, I know there is a problem with the configuration, but I do not know how to configure it

Comment: Edit your question to include your fail2ban config file so we can see what's wrong

Comment: I checked again and found that there is no file that contains the fail2ban configuration. All related folders are also empty @Juxtaposed

Comment: The output asks "Is fail2ban running?". So did you check if it's running?

Comment: I am thankful with your guidance!

How is it possible to run this program when there is no configuration file !?

How do I check if fail2ban is running? @Juxtaposed

Comment: I solved the problem.@Juxtaposed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem was that the fail2ban folder was empty in the path / etc / fail2ban. I downloaded the pack from the official site fail2ban.org and transferred the contents of this pack to / etc / fail2ban.